# SE crawls booth Directory and /index.php file - how can I prevent that?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, seo, web-crawler

I tried to modify my .htaccess file for SEO and do not seem to understand how I can prevent web crawlers to grab **double content** from my website. Because it seems like Google is indexing my website in two manners:

*https://www.example.com/* **AND**
*https://www.example.com/index.php*

This is the .htaccess-Code

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteBase /
# remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.get-to-med\.com
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]
# remove index 
RewriteRule (.*)index$ $1 [R=301]
# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]
# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^get-to-med.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.get-to-med.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
ErrorDocument 404  /diese-seite-existiert-nicht.php
```

Comment: When visiting `/index.php`, don’t you get redirected to `/`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of messing with the .htaccess file endlessly, why not add a canonical tag in the index.php file to the desired version of the page:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/" />
```

Any search engines following the canonical rule will act accordingly.

As for the .htaccess issue, you've got DirectoryIndex index.php in there so that probably has something to do with it (any time the / directory is requested, the index.php file will be returned; may be stored by Google as such).